# soap web service not working in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, soap

i am  trying the following code, soap web service.It is not working .

please help me out.

[Link](http://www.simpleupc.com/api/methods/FetchProductByUPC.php)

[Service](http://www.searchupc.com/service/UPCSearch.asmx)

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
"<soap:Body>\n"
"<request xmlns=\"http://searchupc.com/GenerateBarcode\">\n"
"<auth>5ggpf54TRghbnIvqS2XVGQQ0q6qCNuJ</auth>\n"
"<method>FetchProductByUPC</method>"
"<params>"
"<upc>026274920257</upc>"
"</params>"
"</request>\n"

"</soap:Body>\n"
"</soap:Envelope>\n"
];
NSLog(soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.simpleupc.com/api/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://searchupc.com/GenerateBarcode/" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"SOAP CONNECTED qqq%@",theRequest);
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found wsdlToObjc pretty good. It generates client side ObjC bindings for you from WSDL. You can download it at http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/. The link http://www.priyaontech.com/2012/10/soap-based-webservices-integration-in-an-ios-app/ explains its usage with an example project.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://sudzc.com/ . it will generate xcode project for you.

1: Type the web address of the WSDL to convert (if Protected, then enter username and password )

2: Choose the type of code bundle to create (Objective c) and download.

Just drag and drop the 'Generated' folder to your project and access all the SOAP messages.

Try this. its really easy and simple.

Comment: Just a warning, if your WSDL imports XSDs the generated code will not work, at least this was the case about a year ago, not sure if they have fixed this issue.

Comment: @bennythemink:  I'm using that in my current project and haven't faced any issues till now. I think they have fixed the mentioned issue and thanks for pointing out,appreciated.